# Select from 2D Array by 2 criteria - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 15 * 2 array where the first column represents the area and the second column represents the corresponding circularity to the 15 objects. 
I need to select the row with maximum area while applying the following condition for the circularity to be > 0.9 and <=  1.2

Example:

```
Area      Circularity
-----     -----------
22041     1.1703
23458     2.8425
155       1.4165
37        2.1089
215       1.5692
41        1.0549
659       1.7144
64        1.0508
3         0.3092
584       1.2543
26        1.1132
396       2.9046
1         0
3         0.8488
4         0.4638
```

Expected Result:

```
22041    1.1703
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply your conditional to the second column to check if it is in the range `(0.9 1.2]` and then multiply the resulting `logical` array with the first column. Since `false` will be treated as `0` and `true` will be treated as `1`, this will zero-out the values in the first column that don't meet the criteria for the second column. You can then use the second output of `max` to get the row that contains the maximum value

```
[~, ind] = max(data(:,1) .* (data(:,2) > 0.9 & data(:,2) <= 1.2));
result = data(ind,:)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your great answer. But there is something related to displaying the object. (ind) supposed to be the index of the 15 labeled objects . However the (result) value is correct, the corresponding (ind) value = 2, has to be 1 i.e. index = 1.

Comment: @MohamedFarrag Using the exact data you have provided I get a value of `1`. If your data is different from what you have posted, please update it.

Comment: yes i got my fault it was different due to my sorting. Now it is working properly. thanks again @Suever